# Can you identify the modulation of this signal?

Tags: modes, signal-identification

I picked up a signal on 434 MHz (in Europe). Can you identify the modulation or give me a hint on howto analyze it further? I tried finding a similar signal on https://www.sigidwiki.com without success.

[image: waterfall]

Comment: Some modulations are instantly recognizable from the waterfall, but from the lack of response on this question (and my own failure to recognize it), this doesn't seem to be one of them.  We would need a larger audio sample to identify it.  There is also a signal identification wiki that might help.

Comment: That is an ISM band. This could quite literally be the proprietary transmission scheme of any of thousands of different devices.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at it. It seems like it is not a common modulation indeed.